# Why can't I debug my flask app with VSCode

Tags: flask, visual-studio-code

```
from   flask  import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, g

app = Flask(__main__)

# This is the entrypoint
@app.route('/')
def index():
  # Render page
  return 'Hello'

if __name__=='__main__':
  app.run(debug=True)
```

When I try to run this in the VSCode debugger I get:

```
 * Serving Flask app 'gui' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
No module named gui
```

I set a breakpoint on the line "app.run(debug=True)" and it does execute to that point but when I try to step over or into I get the error.

I tried changing the name of the file from gui.py to app.py and I got the same thing except it says:

```
 * Serving Flask app 'app' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
No module named app
```

What am I doing wrong/missing?

Comment: How you are running the server? Have you tried visiting the address.

Comment: Did you ever work this out? This is happening to me right now only when DEBUG=True is passed into the config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To debug flask with VSCode you need to set your `setting.json` and `launch.json` files correctly, here is a possible configuration:

**settings.json**

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "<your_python_venv_path>",
}
```

**launch.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations" : [
        {
            "name": "local",
            "type": "python",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "request": "launch",
            "program" : "${workspaceFolder}/<path_to_run.py>",
            "console" : "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode" : false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Also take a look [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging)

Comment: I noticed the __name__/__main__ issue shortly after I posted this and corrected it.  I changed my launch.json as you suggest, but I am still getting the same issue.

Comment: Have you read Microsoft's doc? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-flask. Are you using python virtualenvironment right? Please update flask logs after the correction of the application initialization.